# Can i force the Survey list inside sharepoint to work as an exam. where we can have a final score for each user

Tags: 2013, list, permissions, survey, survey-list

I am working on a sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises, and our customer asked us to have the ability to create survey and exams. now i explore the built-in Survey list, which looks promising, but i am not sure how i need to manage these 2 issues:-

1. Seems the built-in survey will provide the ability to create questions, and users can attend the survey. but it does not provide the ability to chose an answer for each question. so users will be attending an exam-like (not a survey), and get a final score.. so is this something i can do inside the built-in survey ?
2. second issue i am facing is regarding the permission. now regarding the permissions on the current sites, we have 2 groups of users; 1) Readers with read-only permission 2) Contributor to create/edit/delete list items (we have tracking list, announcement list & document libraries). but when it comes to survey , the current permission setting will suffer from the following limitations:-

   - Contributor users will not be able to add questions to the survey, and users will need at-least Edit permission to be able to do so. now i do not want to grant contributor users edit permission on the current sites, as they will be able to modify the current lists (document library, announcement & tracking ) settings which i do not want them to have. So is creating a new sub-site, and grant the contributor users Edit permission, so they can add additional survey lists and add questions to the survey the way to go with when it comes to survey lists??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with you, the Survey list as OOTB is pointless in your scenario, it's designed for a simple survey purpose.

It's also uncustomizable list. you can't track the correct answer and you can't calculate the score, so you will need to do additional work  like

- Create a new list for the correct answer to each question.
- Create a workflow to calculate the score based on the above list.

So I suggest building your exam scenario without depending on Survey list, it would be flexible to customize it to match the new requirements.

---

**Regarding permission**, the simplest solution is to break the inheritance and customize its permission based on your requirements.

Comment: now my question is about the built-in survey lists as our customer is asking if this can be done without any development efforts... now i agree with u that the built-in survey can not be used as exams, so at this stage i need to communicate this to our customers, if they are happy to pay for the dev efforts then we are also happy.. regarding breaking the permission, i think i will need to break the permission by creating new sub-site. because if i add a new survey list and i break the permission on the list level

Comment: .. by granting contributor users edit permission, then this will ONLY allow users to add/edit questions inside the current list, but will not allow them to add new survey lists, because adding new survey lists require the users to have edit permison on the site/sub-site itself. so i think i will need to create new subsite, break the site permision by grating contributor users edit permsion, then contributor users will be able to add new survey lists and manage their qestions,, what do u think ? i mean breaking the permision need to be done at the site level not at the list level??

Comment: can u advice more on the above 2 comments please?

Comment: I am sorry for late answer, creating a list in a site will require breaking the inheritance of the site level not on the list level, so your workaround should be working!